# Linux machine restarting

Tags: linux, mount, reboot

I did some changes in /fsab ,also mounted some temporary mounts using mount command .Now the Problem is something has gone wrong and My machine is rebooting automatically after 3 min.

please help me ..How i figure out which is the bad mount that is causing the machine to restart

**Please also tell me the command to stop machine to Automatically Reboot if there.**

Thanks,
Tarun Gupta

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all drives are mounted through their UUID.
use `lsblk -f` to show all driver (and respectely their UUID).

than try to leave only the options `defaults,noatime` for all systems partition and comment all SWAPs, NTFS and FAT partition.

Now reactivate the swap `swapon /dev/sdXN` if the system newly reboot can be a damaged sector in the swap partition.

Then reactivate the NTFS/FAT partition (if any).

If the system still reboot you have probably to check the damage in another part of the system

Answer (score 0):

Tarun, you have to reboot into single user mode ('linux s' at the boot prompt), comment out the new - and offending - entries from /etc/fstab and reboot into multiuser mode.

Then, in multiuser mode, check and recheck the new entries.